# How to change index number of a column to specific words in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a column in a table with 0s and 1s.

I would like to change 0 to 'Not Paying' and 1 for 'Paying' to make it more intuitive for my visuals.

What is the best way to do this?

Should I create a new table, create a new column, or any other idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends if you want a new column o transform it.

Go to Edit Queries. Then you can right click on the column and look for "Replace Values".
With that option you can replace some text to another one.

If the option is not available, first you have to change the type of the column to "text".

Regards,

Comment: Should I use a measure a or a new column @Nacho

Answer (score 1):

Just create a calculated column using the following DAX:

```
New Column :=
SWITCH (
    TRUE (),
    'Table'[Old Column] = 0, "Not Paying",
    'Table'[Old Column] = 1, "Paying"
)
```